# Unable to install 'cocoapods' gem from rubygems.org (bad response backend read error)

Tags: ruby, xcode, rubygems, cocoapods

I'm getting an error when I run 'gem install cocoapods' on OSX Mavericks.

```
$ gem install cocoapods
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'cocoapods' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - bad response backend read error 503 (https://rubygems.global.ssl.fastly.net/quick/Marshal.4.8/cocoapods-0.27.1.gemspec.rz)
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: cocoapods
```

Please note that I can download the cocoapods-0.27.1.gemspec.rz directly.  I am running the latest version of XCode (5.0.1) and the latest version of its CLI tools.  RVM is also configured to run the latest Ruby version (2.0.0p247)

Comment: Make sure your network connection is alright. The command might not work if you are using office network.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though I'm not sure what caused  `read error 503` I was able to work around the problem fairly easily by manually installing the cocoapods.gem.

If anyone else experiences similar problems (with cocoapods or any other gem), download the appropriate gem file (cocoapods-0.27.1.gem in my case) directly from RubyGems.org.  Then run the `gem install cocoapods-0.27.1.gem`.  The install command will scan the working directory first, thus detecting and installing the local gem package, cutting out the broken repository.

Answer (score 38):

Sometimes ,the default source for gem, `https://rubygems.org/`, can't be accessed.

It should be removed by command:

```
gem sources -r https://rubygems.org/
```

And then new source should be added:

```
gem sources -a https://ruby.taobao.org/
```

Update the cache:

```
gem sources -u
```

You can check sources with:

```
gem sources
```

Finally , you can install `cocoapods`:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Comment: $ gem sources -a http://ruby.taobao.org/
Error fetching http://ruby.taobao.org/:
 bad response Not Found 404 (http://ruby.taobao.org/specs.4.8.gz)

Comment: Sorry , it should be "httpS://ruby.taobao.org/"

Comment: Even with "httpS://ruby.taobao.org/" => Error fetching https://ruby.taobao.org/:
 SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://rubygems-china.oss-cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/specs.4.8.gz)

Comment: What is taoboa.org?? is that source reliable at all??

Comment: I don't trust the source "taobao.org". How else can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 28):

Use the below mentioned steps to install Cocoapods in your machine,
I solved the same issue with be below mentioned steps

1.Install command line tools using the command

```
xcode-select --install
```

2.Install Home brew by

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

3.Install Ruby using homebrew

```
brew install ruby
```

4.Check Ruby version

```
ruby -v
```

5.Install Ruby

```
gem source -a http://rubygems.org/
```

6.gem install cocoapods

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

or

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```

7.Go to below folder

```
cd ~/.cocoapods/repos
```

8.Run the below command

```
git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git master
```

9.Go to the directory where Podfile is present and run

```
pod install
```

Comment: I have removed a superfluous `brew install cocoapods` from your steps.

Answer (score 12):

It work for me:

Remove **https** source by command:

```
gem sources -r https://rubygems.org/
```

And then new **http** source should be added:

```
gem sources -a http://rubygems.org/
```

Update the cache:

```
gem sources -u
```

Comment: Worked for me, but it's not ideal since I'd prefer to use https. And to save some head scratching don't forget the trailing / at the end of the URLs

Comment: My god, this is stupidly simple solution that I've never thought!

Comment: Thanks for this simplest solution! IAfter that I removed the http and set back the https.

Answer (score 2):

I found that just removing and re-adding rubygems seemed to work for me ( using the High Sierra on Mac) I prefer to use the official Rubygems repos

```
gem sources -r https://rubygems.org/
gem sources -a https://rubygems.org/
gem sources -u
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

I assume it must have been a glitch..

Answer (score 2):

**Just follow there steps and error is gone**

1.Install command line tools using the command

```
xcode-select --install
```

2.Install Home brew by

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

3.Install cocapods using home-brew, it take care of everything

```
brew install cocoapods
```

4. Last step

```
pod setup
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. Make sure to include `sudo` with install command.

```
gem sources -a http://rubygems.org/
gem sources -u
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Answer (score 0):

For me I had to change rubygems.org to be the gems url used at my company (which caches from rubygems.org).

I did `sudo gem install cocoapods --source <my_company_url_for_gems>`

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
gem sources -r https://rubygems.org/
```

and then

```
sudo gem install cocoapods --source http://rubygems.org
```

Answer (score -1):

Let all http replace https,because the right cocoa pods's sources is https://ruby.taobao.org/