# Ruby gems. Unable to add sources

Tags: ruby, rubygems, cocoapods

I had this problem "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19612185/unable-to-install-cocoapods-gem-from-rubygems-org-bad-response-backend-read-e" and as one of the solutions said I tried to remove/add rubygem sources. It was removed without problem, but when I tried to add it back it's giving me an error.
Here's my action on terminal and response:

```
$ gem sources --add https://rubygems.org/
Error fetching https://rubygems.org/:
    server did not return a valid file (https://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
```

Does anyone know what is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Here is Easy Steps for installing Ruby in your system to help to install Cocoapods in your machine, I solved the same issue with being below mentioned steps.

> 1. Install command line tools using the command

```
xcode-select --install
```

> 2. Install Homebrew by

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

> 3. Install Ruby using homebrew

```
brew install ruby
```

> 4. Check Ruby version

```
ruby -v
```

> 5. Install Ruby

```
gem source -a http://rubygems.org/
```

> 6. gem install cocoa pods

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

### **or**

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```

> 7. Go to below folder

```
cd ~/.cocoapods/repos
```

> 8. Run the below command

```
git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git master
```

> 9. Go to the directory where Podfile is present and run

```
pod install
```

> **Happy Coding**

Answer (score 1):

Steps:
1. sudo gem install cocoapods 
2. pod install
3. pod update

ensure that you are connected to internet. Your system is unable to find the latest version of gems, required by pods